# How to get a proper authentication login for FB app

Tags: facebook, facebook-authentication, facebook-login

I tried pretty much everything, but no matter what I try I always get the wrong login dialog.

I tried this sample snippet.

```
    http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?
  scope=email,user_birthday&
  client_id=123050457758183&
  redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response&
  response_type=token
```

When I input my client_id (app id?) and my redirect_uri (should be https://apps.facebook.com/appnamespace ?) I get a dialog that says "Logging in will not add this app's activity to Facebook."

instead of the first dialog on this documentation.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In your application's advanced settings, change "Enhanced Auth Dialog" to "Disabled" and try again.  Otherwise, you need to configure the Auth Dialog, per the instructions here:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/authentication/

Also, pay attention to the specific `redirect_uri` you provide.  If your Canvas Page has a trailing backslash, make sure you include it.  Otherwise you get the dreaded, "An error occurred.  Please try again later."